# lampp error 403 - Access Forbidden

Tags: php, linux, apache, codeigniter, lampp

I have lampp installed in Fedora, and i have used it without problems for a long time, i was working with the cake framework without issues, i tried to copy the codeigniter folder (from the framework zip) in the HTDOCS folder and was done without problems, but once i tried to access the files throught http://localhost/ci (i made the folde name ci) i receive the following error:

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either
>   read-protected or not readable by the server.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403
>
> localhost Sat 12 Nov 2011 03:55:01 PM AST Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) DAV/2
>   mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/1.0.0c PHP/5.3.5 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1
>   mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

The problem is that i can access other applications i had made before, but i can't access to the frameworks files, i did try to install cake and the same problem arose. what can i do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too had this issue when i changed a directory inside my home directory to serve pages. The directory name is **server**. so i've updated httpd.conf as following,

`DocumentRoot "/home/guna/server"`
`<Directory "/home/guna/server">`

Later i realised setting execute permission is important for other programs to access this directory. As this folder inside my home directory,i changed the permissions for **$HOME** as following:

```
chmod 0755 /home/guna
```

This solved my issue. It may help some one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that it's just a permissions problem. Try running the following command on the folder you created:

```
chmod a+r -R <folder>
```

That gives all users read permission on that folder, and it makes sure the permissions are applied recursively to all files in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

This is a permission problem, hence enter this:

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ci
```